# local variable 'Numeral' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a piece of code in which the user can validate a roman numeral if they want to or not through a yes/no question. It runs fine until the user inputs no and i receive a local variable referenced before assignment error.
Here is my code:

```
def test():
    Test=input('Would you like to test a roman numeral? (yes/no)')  
    while Test != 'yes' and Test != 'no':
        Test=input("sorry, The input you have entered is not valid please try again:")
    if Test == 'yes':
        Numeral=input('please enter the Roman numeral you would like to validate: ')
    
    def valid_roman_numeral(Numeral):
        return (re.search(r"^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",Numeral))\
    
    if(valid_roman_numeral(Numeral)):
        print("The numeral you have entered is correct!")
        test()
    else:
        print("The Numeral entered does not follow all of the rules of roman numerals please try again!")
        test()
test()
```

The exact error I receive is as follows- UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Numeral' referenced before assignment

I've tried to reference the variable earlier but to no luck. I know it's a simple mistake to rectify and i'm probably overlooking something simple so i was hoping another input might help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the user indicated that they didn't want to test a Roman numeral, why are you testing a Roman numeral anyway?  You only assign a value to `Numeral` in the `Test == 'yes'` case, but then try to use it unconditionally.

Comment: Don't check if `Test == 'yes'`. Test if it is `'no'`, and if so, just return. Then the rest of the function can continue under the assumption that the user does, in fact, want to validate a roman numeral.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper, I hadn't realised my problem was my indents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were running the `valid_roman_numeral` function even if the user type "no". A simple check for the "no" answer can solve this

```
def test():
    Test=input('Would you like to test a roman numeral? (yes/no)') 
    
    while Test != 'yes' and Test != 'no':
        Test=input("sorry, The input you have entered is not valid please try again:")
        
    if Test == 'no':
        return
        
    if Test == 'yes':
        Numeral=input('please enter the Roman numeral you would like to validate: ')
    
    def valid_roman_numeral(Numeral):
        return (re.search(r"^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",Numeral))\
    
    if valid_roman_numeral(Numeral):
        print("The numeral you have entered is correct!")
        test()
    else:
        print("The Numeral entered does not follow all of the rules of roman numerals please try again!")
        test()
test()
```